# How to connect Arduino with Internet?

Tags: arduino, wifi, hardware

I have gone through several links online but I have not found any appropriate solution to it. I am wondering if there is a way to connect an Arduino with WiFi without using any shield or any other external hardware. My laptop is connected to WiFi and the arduino board is connected to the laptop with an USB cable. I want to access/run the data for the Arduino using WiFi. Is there a way to do it?
Hope my query makes a sense.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's restate your question for clarity - you want to share the laptop's Internet connection (e.g. via WiFi) with the Arduino connected to the laptop with a USB cable, with no additional hardware?

Assuming I restated it correctly, the Arduino's USB connection provides a virtual "serial port" for communication. This means you can use an "IP over serial" solution for Internet access. One such common and widely supported solution is [PPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol).

However, programing the Arduino with IP over PPP stack requires significant amount of memory and is probably an overkill for whatever it is you're trying to do.

You're probably better off designing a custom-tailored protocol for the serial communication between the Arduino and a small gateway program you can program and run on the laptop.

If you're bent on a complex solution that provides full Internet access to the Arduino, the steps to achieve what you're after are:

1. Program the Arduino with a TCP/IP over PPP protocol stack, running on the serial port. You'll probably need an Arduino MEGA.
2. Setup the laptop to be a PPP endpoint on the Arduino's serial port. For a Windows machine you can refer to [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20140510084329/https://sites.google.com/site/probehouse/networking-the-atari/using-ppp-win7) for information on how to do that.
3. Once the PPP link is up, you can setup the laptop's OS to share Internet access to the PPP link.